# Mysql - How to make this work?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table Products.
It contains the Columns "id,product_name,product_seller,price"

I am trying to create a PHP script to Insert/Update data in the table Products **using the seller name (product_seller)**.
*The issue*
I don't know what mysql query to use in order to get:
 A list with All the products NO matter if the seller has it or not and if the seller has the products to give me the details (id,product_name,product_seller,price).

EXAMPLE of what i want to get:

1 - apples - seller A - 12
2 - banana -             - 
3 - oil         -             -
4 - dvd    - seller A - 25
The product_name must be DISTINCT

Thanks in advance!

* Query must be something like "SELECT DISTINCT product_name FROM Products and let me know where Seller A has the product, at what price, what id what product WHERE seller_name = 'seller A'...yet, show me all products, n matter if seller has it"

Comment: use two different queries (inline views) 1 to get distinct products, another to join back to get all teh sellers and details.

Comment: Please choose a better description (title) for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a straight forward subquery to get a unique list of products then an outer join to get the seller info.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Product_name, B.product_Seller, B.Price
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID, Product_Name FROM products) A
LEFT JOIN Products B
  on A.ID = B.ID
 and B.product_Seller = 'seller A'
```

The LEFT JOIN will ensure you return all the products and only seller information related to the items for 'SELLER A'

SQL generally operates best on data SETS.  So I first generate a set of unique IDs and products and then LEFT JOIN this to the sellers product data you desire.  The left join ensures we keep all the items.  The filtering of the seller MUST be on the JOIN itself and not in the where clause.  Otherwise the left join in essence becomes an inner as the NULLS generated from the outer join are removed.

```
 SELECT A.ID, A.Product_name, B.product_Seller, B.Price
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID, Product_Name FROM products) A
 LEFT JOIN Products B
   on A.ID = B.ID
 WHERE B.product_Seller = 'seller A'
```

Wouldn't get the desired result.  This is because the where clause is applied after the join so the items that are not associated to the seller would be excluded.  Since you want those records, you must use a left join and apply the limit on the JOIN so the items not associated to the seller are returned.

When I initially started with SQL I had trouble with this type of logic.  It wasn't until I considered data in terms of "SETS" and how those sets related, that how to solve these questions became easier.

Comment: `where B.product_seller = ...` the alias should be included

Comment: Wouldn't matter.  A only contains ID and product name.  But for clarity yes it would be B.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the

> SELECT * FROM Products_Table ;

this will obtain all the table values

Comment: Yes, but this will list all sellers as well :/

Comment: you want to see the Product names only ?